# Amazon AWS WebApp with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have built a mobile application that needs to connect to my SpringBoot-WebApp which in turn has a MongoDB and some other things in the background.

I want to deploy this WebApp at Amazon AWS, but I am overwhelmed by all the possibilities. So far, I have just created it as a .jar, and ran it that way, and it worked fine at my other server.
Now, for traffic reasons and such, we want to move it to AWS. I have found out, that I need to create a .war instead of a .jar, which is not a problem. I then learned to upload this .war to Elastic Beanstalk. However, my application needs to connect to a MongoDB. I have logged on to AWS via SSH and installed MongoDB there and created the database, but it does not seem like this is the right way to do it.

It'd greatly appreciate if anyone could give me a hint on how to do this as I am very confused.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I believe you're running this stack for some time - given the date this question was posted - and I have the very same requirements from yours. Could you share your thoughts on it? Did you have any problems, how do you backup your data, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear if you are doing this, but don't run MongoDB on Elastic Beanstalk. The Elastic Beanstalk server you have it installed on may be automatically deleted by AWS. In general you do not want to manually install anything on Elastic Beanstalk as it is a managed environment where servers may be automatically created or deleted based on server load.

Amazon doesn't provide a MongoDB service directly, so you either need to install and manage MongoDB on an EC2 instance (or fleet of instances) yourself, or use a third party MongoDB service that runs on AWS. You could use something like [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/) which provides a MongoDB service that runs on AWS. This allows your network traffic between your web servers and database servers to stay within the AWS network, which you will want for both performance and security reasons.

If you use MongoLab just make sure you choose to create your database in the same AWS region that you are deploying your application to. Also, I wouldn't recommend their free sandbox databases for any sort of critical production application.

If you decide to install and manage MongoDB on AWS yourself, here is some documentation from [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/mongodb-on-the-aws-cloud-new-quick-start-reference-deployment/), and some from [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. I have installed MongoDB on my EC2 instance, but I don't know how to let my application connect to it, when I have it in the Elastic Beanstalk environment

Comment: You would have to open up the security group of your EC2 instance to allow access from the security group you are using for your Elastic Beanstalk instances.

Comment: Okay, one more thing: The webserver runs on some port that I opened for all IPs (after all, my mobile app needs to connect to this web app). So I created a new inbound rule for the particular security group. Is it safe to open a port for any IP?